# how to toggle the alternative bits of number in c

Tags: c, bit

I want to know how to toggle alternative bits in a number?

for eg if number is  1100 1001
   the result should be 1001 1100

Comment: `number ^= 0x55555555;` (for 32bit number) or `number ^= 0xaaaaaaaa;` for the odd bits.

Comment: @user1754194 : Check my answer does it work for you ?

Answer (score 3):

XOR'ing with an alternating bitmask:

11001001 ^ 01010101

Answer (score 0):

```
int a1= 0xA9, // 1100 1001 
    a2= 0x9A; // 1001 1100

int mask= a1 ^ a2;  // the toggling mask 
                    // (bits different between a1 and a2)

int test= a1 ^ mask;

printf("mask= %02x, test= %02x\n", mask, test);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
char toggleOddBits(char number)
{
    for(int bitPos = sizeof(number) * 8 - 1 ; bitPos >= 0 ; bitPos--) {

        // If bit position is odd
        if ( 0 == (bitPos % 2)) {

            number ^= 1 << bitPos; // Toggle bit at bitPosition
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

**You can change it to `int` or `long`**